# How to retrieve nested models in sails?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have modelA with one to many relationship with modelB and modelB has many to many relationship with modelC. How can I retrieve a record in modelA returning also the related data in modelB and modelC? I'm also thinking of using `through` but I can't find any documentation regarding it.

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this documentation.
http://beta.sailsjs.org/#!documentation/reference/ModelAssociations/Many-to-Many.html